# Calculate the power of a number in input

Tags: java

I was writing a practice program in Java for one number raised to the other. Unknowingly I made a peculiar mistake which I caught. However the answer still came out correct no matter the input I give. Below is the piece of code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int count;
    int num1, num2, result = count =1;
    try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the 1st number");
        num1 = n1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number");
        num2 = n1.nextInt();
    }
    while(count<=num2)
    {
        if(num2!=0)
        {
            result = num1*result;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num1+" to the power "+num2+" is "+num1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(num1+" to the power "+num2+" is "+result);
}
```

I'm going crazy as to what exactly happened. how come the statement "System.out.println(num1+" to the power "+num2+" is "+num1)" didn't print value of num1.

Following is the output:

```
 {
 Enter the 1st number
 100
 Enter the 2nd number
 0
 100 to the power 0 is 1
 }
```

I use ECLIPSE LUNA to code java.

Comment: Can you share the code where you declare your variable and also how your read them. Please change the heading of this.

Comment: @StackFlowed: I will write the entire code. Although i checked with input other that 100 to the power 0 like 2 to the power 4 and 4 to the power 5 and so on. All are absolutely correct.

Comment: Too bad you don't show the initialization of the variables.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I have written the entire code. Please review

Comment: @StackFlowed : As you said i have written the entire code once again please review.

Comment: @Dhananjay: are you sure this is the entire code, because if `count` is not initialized, it can normally not run the `while` loop...

Comment: Yeah, the answer that @Eran gave is correct. You initialise it to 1, so when num2 is 0, you'll not enter the `while`

Comment: @CommuSoft count is initialized to 1.

Comment: @forgivenson: oh didn't catched the second line. But then the code is still incorrect because an identifier is declared multiple times.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Yeah thanks even i didn't noticed the condition in while was so right that an if and else statement was unnecessary. I just thought after writing the whole thing what if an input is 0 then and for that reason i introduced if and else statement.

Comment: @Dhananjay: you can also optimize the code further so it runs in *O(log e)* with *e* the value of the exponent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, assuming that you initialize `count` and `result` to 1 (which, after your edit, I see was a correct assumption), if `num2` is 0, the loop is not entered at all, and all you see is the output printed by the last line (after the loop).

Therefore it doesn't matter what you have inside the loop in this case - `System.out.println(num1+" to the power "+num2+" is "+num1);` will never be executed when `num2` is 0.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing - result is set to 1 initially has to be the case.

Comment: @Eran: Oh i didnt  see that coming. Jeez thanks guys. So in this case even  if i dont use "If" and "else". I would get the result correct.